# Multi Map Ravendb find documents based on documents present in another collection

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have 2 collections in Ravendb. **IdentifiedDupEmployees** contain the duplicate employee information along with count of how many duplicate documents.
**Employee** contains the entire employee documents. I basically need to find the employee documents from employee collection based on firstname, lastname,DateofBirth,address1 present in **IdentifiedDupEmployees**.

I have written a multi map index. Please help me tweak it. Since currently it is returning everything present in Employee collection, I want only those documents returned from employee collection whose employee details present in IdentifiedDupEmployees collection

```
public class IdentifiedDupemployees {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
            public string address1 { get; set; }
            public int count {get; set;}
}

Public class employee 
{
           public string Ids {get; set;}
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
            public string address1 { get; set; }
}


namespace DuplicatePatient.Storage.Indexes
{
    class DupFindPatientId: AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<DupFindPatientId.Result>
    {

        public class Result
        {

            public string Ids { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }

            public string address1 { get; set; }
        }
        public DupFindPatientId()
        {

            AddMap<IdentifiedDupPatients>(entities => from a in entities

                                                      select new
                                                      {
                                                          Ids = (string)null,
                                                          FirstName = a.FirstName,
                                                          LastName = a.LastName,
                                                          DateOfBirth = a.DOB,
                                                          address1 = a.address1
                                                      });

            AddMap<Patient>(entities => from b in entities
                                        //from c in b.FirstName
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            Ids = b.Id,
                                            FirstName = b.FirstName,
                                            LastName = b.LastName,
                                            DateOfBirth = b.DateOfBirth,
                                            address1 = b.Address1
                                        });

            Reduce = results => from result in results
                                group result by new
                                {
                                    result.FirstName,
                                    result.LastName,
                                    result.DateOfBirth,
                                    result.address1

                                   }
                                    into g   

                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Ids = g.Select(x => x.Ids).Where(x => x != null).First(),
                                        FirstName = g.Key.FirstName,
                                        LastName = g.Key.LastName,
                                        DateOfBirth = g.Key.DateOfBirth,
                                        address1 = g.Key.address1

                                    };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the index to include a Duplicate flag, and you can filter on that during query

```
public class IdentifiedDupemployees {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
            public string address1 { get; set; }
            public int count {get; set;}
}

Public class employee 
{
           public string Ids {get; set;}
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
            public string address1 { get; set; }
}


namespace DuplicatePatient.Storage.Indexes
{
    class DupFindPatientId: AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<DupFindPatientId.Result>
    {

        public class Result
        {

            public string Ids { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }

            public string address1 { get; set; }
        }
        public DupFindPatientId()
        {

            AddMap<IdentifiedDupPatients>(entities => from a in entities

                                                      select new
                                                      {
                                                          Ids = (string)null,
                                                          FirstName = a.FirstName,
                                                          LastName = a.LastName,
                                                          DateOfBirth = a.DOB,
                                                          address1 = a.address1,
                                                          Duplicate = true
                                                      });

            AddMap<Patient>(entities => from b in entities
                                        //from c in b.FirstName
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            Ids = b.Id,
                                            FirstName = b.FirstName,
                                            LastName = b.LastName,
                                            DateOfBirth = b.DateOfBirth,
                                            address1 = b.Address1,
                                            Duplicate = false
                                        });

            Reduce = results => from result in results
                                group result by new
                                {
                                    result.FirstName,
                                    result.LastName,
                                    result.DateOfBirth,
                                    result.address1

                                   }
                                    into g   

                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Ids = g.Select(x => x.Ids).Where(x => x != null).First(),
                                        FirstName = g.Key.FirstName,
                                        LastName = g.Key.LastName,
                                        DateOfBirth = g.Key.DateOfBirth,
                                        address1 = g.Key.address1,
                                        Duplicate = g.Any(x=>Duplicate)
                                    };
        }
```